# Generate PFX file using P7B file with private key data in text format

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, encryption

I have the certificate in P7B format and along with I have private key data in text file format as below. Can anyone please help how can I generate the PFX certificate using this data?

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
// Long Encrypted text
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 2):

This command line will generate a PFX file `cert+key+chain.pfx` from a P7B file `cert+chain.p7b` and a private key `privkey.pem`:

```
$ openssl pkcs7 -in cert+chain.p7b -print_certs | \
  openssl pkcs12 -export -in - -inkey privkey.pem -out cert+key+chain.pfx
```